# Keeping saved data in tab when navigating between tabs

Tags: c#, tabs, tabcontrol

I have a program where you can enter data into text boxes in a tab control, then save the information you enter for later use. I have an 'Add tab' button, so I can add new tabs and enter new data, unfortunately when I click on the new tab and then go back to the previous tab my saved data in the previous tab has disappeared.

When I close the program and re run it, my data is there again, it is only when I navigate between tabs that my tab data disappears.

How do I make sure my data stays saved when I navigate between tabs?

Here is my add tab button code to give you a better understanding

int seasonYear = 12;

```
        TabPage newTP = new TabPage();

        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTP)

        int TabPageNumber = tabControl1.SelectedIndex + 1; // +1 one up from current

        tabControl1.TabPages[TabPageNumber].Text = "Season " + (12 - TabPageNumber);

        txtPosition.Clear();
        txtPoints.Clear();
        txtWon.Clear();
        txtDrawn.Clear();
        txtLost.Clear();


        tabControl1.SelectTab(TabPageNumber);
        btnRemovetab.Enabled = true; // We now have something to delete

        panel1.Parent = tabControl1.SelectedTab; 

        ShowData();

    }
```

Comment: You call txtXYZ.Clear(), that controls lay on your existing tab page (not in the new one, it's just created and it's empty). That's why content disappears...

Comment: looks like it's by your fault, switching tabpage won't change any current texts, values contained by the controls on the tabpages.

Comment: I want the content to disappear for the new tab, but when I go back to the previous tab, my data is gone, I want the data to save in the tab for later use

Comment: you are using the same textboxes for the new created tabs, that is why if you don't clear, the content is shown in the new tab. I suggest you create an usercontrol with all the textboxes you want, and when you create a new tab just create a new instance of the usercontrol and add it to your tab